# Write a BigInteger variable into a BitArray and vice-versa

Tags: c#, vb.net, biginteger, bitarray

I am using the `BigInteger` type from `System.Numerics`.

For instance:

```vb
Dim Mult17 As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("1453453452342347")
```

Questions:

1. Given a `BigInteger`, how do I convert it into a `BitArray`?
   (Clearly I want the `BitArray` to hold the binary 10101...  representation of the number stored in the `BigInteger` variable, and I would like to have the option to have it stored in one way or the reverse way.)
2. I also need to go back from a `BitArray` to a `BigInteger`.

Note that there's no sign concern: I am dealing only with positive integers. VB.NET or C# examples will be fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Well it looks like you can take a BigInteger to a byte[] using [.ToByteArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray.aspx).

And lucky for you, BitArray takes a byte[] as a [constructor parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a.aspx).

To go backwards, BitArray to byte[], use this [extension](http://geekswithblogs.net/dbrown/archive/2009/04/05/convert-a-bitarray-to-byte-in-c.aspx), then pass into BigInteger in the constructor

It looks like it should work. Full disclosure, I am too lazy to test this.

Comment: Hmmm, very interesting. A first question though is how the ByteArray relates to the BitArray ? Can i expect to just "streamline" the bits into the bitarray. I have no idea of the internal structure of the biginteger ?

Comment: @Pam: Why dont you simply TRY it? Hint: A Biginteger 5 .ToArray gives you an array with ONE element and the elements value is 5 ...

Comment: Not .ToArray - .ToByteArray.